# how to click a button having vbscript used in its onclick function

Tags: java, selenium, vbscript, onclick

I have the following HTML for a button, i want to click this button.I am new to Selenium and dont know much about it.I guess it is vbscript used in it and I dont know how to trigger the click function on it.
I am using Java, Selenium , Win 8, IE 10.

```
<span style="font-family: arial; font-size: 12px; cursor: hand;" onclick="vbscript:cmdSave_OnClick"> 
<img width="16" height="16" class="btnRowIcon" src="../../../../Images/V10Icons/Save.gif"/>
```

I have used the following but it didnt worked for me:

```
 idriver.findElement(By.id("vbscript:cmdSave_OnClick")).click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vbscript:CmdSave_OnClick is not the id of the button. Since the button does not have any ID, you can use xpath for selenium to identify and click on it. If you can post more html surrounding this button, we can suggest you something for xpath.

Comment: I have added some more info about that button. is it sufficient now?

Comment: If this is the only img with class="btnRowIcon" then use this -- idriver.findElement(By.className("btnRowIcon")).click();